# Как обновить обьект json а не создать новый?

Tags: python, json

Есть json файл:

```
{
"users":[
{"id": 1,
"cash": 100},
{"id": 2,
"cash": 300},
{"id": 3,
"cash": 500}
]}
```

Я пытаюсь поменять значение одного из ключей:

```
with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    obj = json.load(file)
    obj["users"][0]["cash"] = 50
    json.dump(obj,file)
```

Но оно просто создает новый обьект:

```
{
"users":[
{"id": 1,
"cash": 100},
{"id": 2,
"cash": 300},
{"id": 3,
"cash": 500}
]}{"users": [{"id": 1, "cash": 50}, {"id": 2, "cash": 300}, {"id": 3, "cash": 500}]}
```

помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

откройте файл для чтения и запишите в переменную, после чего откройте в режиме записи и запишите изменения

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    obj = json.load(f)
    obj["users"][0]["cash"] = 50
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(obj, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать это за одно открытие, выглядеть будет так:

```py
import json


with open("data.json", "r+") as file:
    obj = json.load(file)
    obj["users"][0]["cash"] = 50

    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(obj, file)
    file.truncate()
```